# Is there any .config file in Yocto similar to buildroot

Tags: linux, configuration, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I was using buildroot previously and now I am switching to Yocto. There is .config file generated by buildroot which contains all the packages that are going to be present in the file system, the compiler used, kernel version and bootloader etc.

Do we have something similar to this in Yocto. Or is there any bitbake command like `make menuconfig`.

I have seen some lines in recipes like the below:

```
 if 'CONFIG_UBOOT=y\n' in features:
```

What is `features` here means

Thanks for your time

Comment: In which recipes did you see these lines ? Perhaps in yocto classes ? You can customize the set of packages to install using `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable. In addition, you can also refine your distribution by using `DISTRO_FEATURES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no .config in yocto, But yocto maintains a list of packages that are installed in the rootfs image in a .manifest files located at

```
Manifest Path: build/tmp/deploy/images/<machine>/<rootfs_image_name>.manifest.
```